# How to overlap elements in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this stepper attached as an example in fiddle.

```css
.stepper-wrapper {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.stepper-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.stepper-item::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item .step-counter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.stepper-item.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.stepper-item.active .step-counter {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 3px;
  top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.stepper-item.completed .step-counter {
  background-color: red;
}

.stepper-item.completed::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.stepper-item:first-child::before {
  content: none;
}

.stepper-item:last-child::after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper-wrapper">
  <div class="stepper-item completed">
    <div class="step-counter"></div>
    <div class="step-name">First</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepper-item completed">
    <div class="step-counter"></div>
    <div class="step-name">Second</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepper-item active">
    <div class="step-counter"></div>
    <div class="step-name">Third</div>
  </div>
  <div class="stepper-item">
    <div class="step-counter"></div>
    <div class="step-name">Forth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to overlap this active element so that these left and right lines go until the first (outer) circle.

This part...

[image]

How to make this in CSS?

It should be something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our main goal here is to cover-up the space between the actual element and its border.

The space can be filled by an inset box-shadow.
It will hide all the content under it; just give the right amount of `spread` with `zero blur` :)

Just add this snippet to the element:

```css
box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white inset;
```

Here's the edited snippet

```css
.stepper-wrapper {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.stepper-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;

}

.stepper-item::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.stepper-item .step-counter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.stepper-item.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.stepper-item.active .step-counter {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  /* Here it is */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white inset;
  padding: 3px;
  top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.stepper-item.completed .step-counter {
  background-color: red;
}

.stepper-item.completed::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.stepper-item:first-child::before {
  content: none;
}

.stepper-item:last-child::after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper-wrapper">
      <div class="stepper-item completed">
        <div class="step-counter"></div>
        <div class="step-name">First</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stepper-item completed">
        <div class="step-counter"></div>
        <div class="step-name">Second</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stepper-item active">
        <div class="step-counter"></div>
        <div class="step-name">Third</div>
      </div>
      <div class="stepper-item">
        <div class="step-counter"></div>
        <div class="step-name">Forth</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this one for your problem, I hope this helps you.

```css
.stepper-item.active .step-counter::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Snippet doesn't work... No explanation...

Comment: I just use another after for your style and in that make another border outside of the inside one with white color and 3px